# Add event click into marker openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Good day, I'm trying to add events to dynamically programmed markers on a map. The markers do show on the screen but when you click to show a div, instead of just showing the div related to the bookmark, activate the event click on all the div on the screen.

Where the marker is created is when invoking the function crearMarcadores and send the coordinates and the variable cc to use for the id of the div.

```
var centro = ol.extent.getCenter(boundingBox);
crearMarcadores(centro, cc);
```

The divs if you create them correctly, as I understand it must be a div for each marker.

And where I'm almost sure is my mistake is in:

```
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer) {
            return feature;
  });
```

Since it executes a foreach, and should only return the marker feature. But I do not know how to run it only in the current marker. Although all the examples I have found are with foreach.

For your valuable help, thank you very much.

```js
    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([-90.204114, 13.866291]),
        name: 'nombre',
        population: 4000,
        rainfall: 500
    });

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
     anchor: [0.5, 46],
     anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
     anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
     opacity: 0.75,
     src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/data/icon.png'
        }))
    });
    iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [iconFeature]
    });

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: vectorSource
    });

    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ /*layer con los poligonos*/
        source: new ol.source.Vector()
    })

    function crearMarcadores(centroPoligono, CentroCosto) {

        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
         geometry: new ol.geom.Point(centroPoligono),
         name: CentroCosto,
         population: 4000,
         rainfall: 500
        });
        vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
        iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

        //------------start creation popup
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute("id", CentroCosto);
        div.setAttribute("style", "width: 580px; height: 400px; float: left");
        document.body.appendChild(div);

        var element = document.getElementById(CentroCosto);

        var popup = new ol.Overlay({
         element: element,
         positioning: 'bottom-center',
         stopEvent: false
        });
        map.addOverlay(popup);
        //------------end creation popup

        // --------------display popup on click
        map.on('click', function(evt) {
     
     var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
       return feature;
      });
     if (feature) {
      var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
      popup.setPosition(coord);
      $(element).popover({
       'placement': 'top',
       'html': true,
       'content': feature.get('name')
      });
      $(element).popover('show');
     } else {
      $(element).popover('destroy');
     }
        });
    //---------------end display popup on click

    
    } //termina funcion crearMarcadores

    function generarMapas() {

    var FechaInicial = '';
    var FechaFinal = '';
    var Finca = '';
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "FrmMapaAvanceRiego.aspx\/FillMapas",
     data: '{FechaInicial: "' + FechaInicial + '", FechaFinal: "' + FechaFinal + '", Finca: "' + Finca + '"}',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg) {
      var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);
      coordenadas = [];
      cc = [];
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
       coordenadas[i] = item.Coordenadas;
       cc[i] = item.CentroDeCostoLote;
       crearPoligonos(coordenadas[i], cc[i]);

      });
     },
     error: errores
    });
    }

    function errores(msg) {
     alert('Error: ' + msg.responseText);
    }

    function crearPoligonos(coordenada, cc) {
    //console.log(coordenada);
    console.log(cc);
    var coordenadas = coordenada.split(' ') // Separamos por espacio
     .map(function(data) {
      var info = data.split(','), // Separamos por coma
       coord = { // Creamos el obj de coordenada
        lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
        lng: parseFloat(info[0])
       };

      return coord;
     });

    var parserJSTS = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

    var poly = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(function(_ref) {
      var lng = _ref.lng,
       lat = _ref.lat;
      return [lng, lat];
     })])
    });

    var boundingBox = poly.getGeometry().getExtent()
    var polybbox = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(boundingBox)
    })

    var [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] = boundingBox

    var porcentaje = 0.50
    var newXmax = xmin + ((xmax - xmin) * porcentaje)

    var newBoundingBox = [xmin, ymin, newXmax, ymax]

    var polybbox50 = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(newBoundingBox)
    })

    var polybbox50jsts = parserJSTS.read(polybbox50.getGeometry())

    var polyjsts = parserJSTS.read(poly.getGeometry())

    var intersectionJSTSGeometry = polyjsts.intersection(polybbox50jsts)

    var intersectionGeometry = parserJSTS.write(intersectionJSTSGeometry)

    var newPoly = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: intersectionGeometry
    })
    //console.log(boundingBox)

    newPoly.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#02ABFF'
     })
    }))

    // Descomentar para ver los bounding boxes
    //      layer.getSource().addFeature(polybbox)
    //      layer.getSource().addFeature(polybbox50)
    layer.getSource().addFeature(poly)
    layer.getSource().addFeature(newPoly)


    var centro = ol.extent.getCenter(boundingBox);
    //console.log(centro);

    crearMarcadores(centro, cc);
    }

    //------------start creation map
    var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
     new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
       key: 
    'AudCyoI6al0eAZmQhwmI1IG9AOdGH8DHHk6PsiGta1faEACulxawFU9KV-XAvZ8f',
       imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels'
      })
     }),
     layer, vectorLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
     attributionOptions: ({
      collapsible: false
     })
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
     center: [-90.365730, 13.954185],
     zoom: 9,
     projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
    });
    // --------------end creation map
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0">
    </div>
    <div id="popup"></div>
```

Comment: Are you aware that there is a popup available in OpenLayer? Is there any reason to not use it?

Comment: You could indicate me how to use it correctly, since I did not know that there was such an option. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that comment above, you are actually already using it. It's called "Overlay"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEachFeatureAtPixel` ([api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel)) goes through every feature *of every layer* at that location. So you might get unexpected results from other layers.

But the function also let's you define a layerFilter which decides if you want to include a layer or not.

Example:

```
map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource1,
  myKey: 'magic' // arbitrary property to distinguish between the layers
});

map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource2,
  myKey: 'someotherlayer'
});

// this only gives back the first feature at this position
// on the layer with the property `myKey` equal to `'magic'`
const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
  pixel,
  function(someFeature){ return someFeature; }, // stop at the very first feature
  {
    layerFilter: function(layer) { return layer.get('myKey') === 'magic'; }
  }
);
```